# Java Char Buffer that automatically grows and can be re-used

Tags: java, char, buffer

Hello Java Developers:

I'm looking for a built in class to store a sequence of characters.  It needs to meet the following criteria:

1. It can store char values (not just byte values)
2. It has an append method that causes the underlying data structure to automatically grow in size should it exceed the pre-allocated size.
3. Has a method to clear the contents (i.e. re-use the memory).
4. Can read the entry at a given index.

I've found several options that meet some of these requirements but not all of them.  For instance:

1. CharBuffer does not satisfy 2.
2. StringBuffer does not satisfy 3.
3. ByteArrayOutputStream does not satisfy 1.
4. CharArrayWriter does not satisfy 4.

Am I misinterpreting the documentation for one of these classes, or does someone out there know of a data structure that meets all 4 criteria?

Edit: 
By criteria 3, I don't mean free memory to GC.

I'm in the situation where I need to repeatedly allocate and de-allocate several of these buffers.  In my use case, these buffers end up being fairly large (~ 100 KB) and I would have several threads using such buffers.

I'm aware that I could just create a buffer, use it and then have it GC-ed when I'm done.  However, I've found that the JVM garbage collector runs quite slowly when you are constantly allocating and de-allocating a large percent of the JVM (and physical machine's) memory.  I've found speed improvements when I start micromanaging the memory (like one can do in C++) by allocating a buffer once and then re-using it (thus triggering garbage collection less frequently).

Comment: StringBuffer/StringBuilder does not satisfy 3? How so?

Comment: Why not use an `arraylist`?

Comment: to @HovercraftFullOfEels point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#delete%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Also to @HovercraftFullOfEels point. To actually free the char buffer memory, follow the delete call with a trimToSize().

Answer (score 2):

StringBuilder/StringBuffer should satisfy 3 fine since `delete(...)` should do what you need. Or why not simply create a new instance and let the old one be GC'd?

Answer (score 2):

StringBuffer is able to delete it content

```
buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution that I've found: 
StringBuilder has .setLength(0) which I can use to get the buffer to start re-writing contents.

(A dedicated .reset() method would have been nice.)